# scikit learn: learning curve without information leak?

Tags: scikit-learn

I would like to generate a learning curve for an LinearSVC estimator that is using countVectorizer to extract the features. The countVectorizer is also applying some feature selection step.

I could do the following:

1. fit the vectorizer on all data, including selection of top N features
2. use these features in fitting the linearSVC
3. use the linearSVC as the estimator in sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve()

But I think that it will result in information leak: information based on all data will be used to select features for the smaller sets used in the learning curve.

Is this correct?
Is there a way to use the built-in sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve() with countVectorizer without information leak?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a pipeline in conjunction with the `learning_curve`.
The pipeline will call `fit_transform` of the transformer when training and only `transform` when testing. The `learning_curve` will also apply cross-validation which can be controlled by the parameter `cv`.

With this pipeline, there is no leak of information. Here, is an example using an integrated toy library in scikit-learn.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve


categories = [
    'alt.atheism',
    'talk.religion.misc',
]
# Uncomment the following to do the analysis on all the categories
#categories = None

data = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories)

pipeline = make_pipeline(
    CountVectorizer(), TfidfTransformer(), LinearSVC()
)

learning_curve(pipeline, data.data, data.target, cv=5)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Is there a way to extract the list of selected features from the pipeline? I would like to compare the selected features from several datasets going through the same pipeline.

Comment: Once fitted, you can access to the underlying fitted estimator (transformer or predicor) using `named_steps`: e.g. `pipeline.named_steps['linearsvc'].coef_`